# Render user input in a div in React

Tags: reactjs

I have multiple inputs and I'm currently rendering them in the console but I want a certain user input (the 'title' input) rendered in a div or any html element when submit is clicked. I presume I just need to change the code in my handleSubmit() function to do this.
What exactly do I need to add/change in my code to do this?

```
constructor() {
  super()
  this.state = { 
    title: '',
    goal: '',
    tech: '',
    features: '',
    details: ''
  }

  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
}

handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value 
  })
}

handleSubmit(event) {
  const {
    title,
    goal,
    tech,
    features,
    details
  } = this.state;
  event.preventDefault();
  alert(`Plan Title: ${title}, Goal: ${goal}`)
}

render() {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <label className="label-title">Project Title:</label>
        <input name="title" id="title" type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} required aria-required="true"/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label className="label-goal">Goal: </label>
        <input name="goal" id="goal" type="text" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
      </div>
      <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Save plan" />
    </form>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently updating the state upon user's input change. So all you need to do is add another state value that is used for displaying in UI. (apparently, you don't want to directly show the state value connected to user's input change, that is, `this.state.title`)

To summarize:

1. add another state value, say, `submittedTitle` to your state.
2. upon submission, update the value
3. display it on the UI

Code could be like this:

```
constructor() {
  super()
  this.state = { 
    ...,
    submittedTitle: '',
  };
  ...
}

handleSubmit(event) {
  const {
    ...
    submittedTitle,
  } = this.state;
  event.preventDefault();
  this.setState({ submittedTitle });
  ...
}

render() {
  return (
    ...
    ...
      <div>{this.state.submittedTitle}</div>
    ...
  );
}
```